# Question about Parity Root Test

Tags: polynomials

> What is the  "Parity Root Test" for polynomials  ? and how to use it for showing that the all the roots of the equation
>   $x^4-x^3+2x+1=0$ are or aren't integers ?

I didn't have any information about the "Parity Root Test" before encounter this problem in math contest  prerperation material.

Please help me understanding this topic very well 
Thank you for your help.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post a more specific question. That said, in general if a polynomial $q(x)$ has an integer root, then it has an integer root modulo $p$---the Parity Root Test is basically this observation for $p = 2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, parity probably means "odd" or "even".

Thus, for your example, the equation

$$x^4-x^3+2x+1=0$$

has no integer roots, since if $x$ is an integer, the LHS will always be odd, hence can't be zero.

Hint: Check two cases ($x$ even, $x$ odd).